# how to check if there's a string in the command line

Tags: c, string, unix

I have this command line:> write_strings "Hello World!" a.txt b.txt dir/a.txt. 
all the elements (command, string, file names) go into an array of char pointer. how can I take an element and check if it's a string or a file name? 
I don't mean the exact code lines, buts just need the idea. the program should return an error if there's no string.

Comment: First step - are you aware of command line arguments?

Comment: A file name is a string.  Be precise in defining what you want, and the answer will often become apparent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an API such as [stat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) or [access](http://linux.die.net/man/2/access) to check if the file pointed to by a path exists. There is no fundamental distinction between filepaths and regular strings when they are passed to your process.

If you're using the standard `main(int argc, char *argv[])` convention, you can loop through `argv`, checking each one to see if it's a file via one of the previously-mentioned system calls.

Comment: I am using main(int argc, char *argv[]) but we haven't seen the system calls you mentioned in lectures, so I'm guessing we're not supposed to use it

Comment: How about the `open` system call? If you don't pass the `O_CREAT` flag it should fail.

Comment: First, you should tag your question as `homework` to help us help you better. Secondly, `fopen` will return NULL if the file doesn't exist when opened with `"r"` mode.

Comment: I'm opening the file with "w". so if it doesn't exist it will create one. I basically need to copy the string in to the file/s I get. but if there's no string at all I'm supposed to print error.

Answer (score 1):

Every string that can be passed on a command line is a potential pathname, since the only restriction in both cases is that there can't be any NULs.

A program with a command line syntax in which a specific argument might or might not be used as a pathname (depending on some vague definition of "filename-ish strings" or even a file existence test) is a bad design. Each argument should have a meaning defined by its order in the argument list, or by being associated with an option like `-m msg` or `-o outputfile`.

A well-behaved unix program will let the user create a file called `Hello world!` if he wants.

Comment: that's the thing. the string can act as a file name so I don't know how to tell the difference. how do I know if I have a string there or not?

Comment: Everything on the command line *is* a string. Strings are the only thing that can be put on a command line. If your teacher is trying to tell you otherwise, your teacher is an idiot.

Comment: no, I understand that. but is there no way to tell the difference between "XXX" and x.txt for example? visually you can tell which is supposed to be a string and which is a file name. is there no way to know?

Comment: Specifically, if `write_strings "hello world" a.txt` is valid but `write_strings b.txt a.txt` is invalid because you refuse to consider `"b.txt"` to be a valid string to write into the file `a.txt`, your program is stupidly designed.

Comment: @littlerunaway: `XXX` is valid as a file name, as well as `x.txt` is a valid as a string.

Comment: btw, is there any difference between writing "a.txt" and a.txt in the command line?

Comment: @littlerunaway In general, there's not. There are ways to tell that only work on Windows (and there are a handful of commands that do this - findstr and start are two examples), but they're not standard C, and won't work on unix which I see you tagged your question as... and what would you do do with "a b.txt" meaning a filename with a space in it?

Answer (score 0):

not regarding how meaningful the program might or might not be - you can compare the single characters of your `char *argv[]` by looping through them via `argv[i][j]`. If every string includes a ".txt" you do not have a string, which is not a filename in your context

Comment: but in unix ther's no meaning to .txt from what I was told. I can basically get any file name.

Comment: that's true, but from how I understood your question and the comments your command line arguments are supposed to be of a given form (e.g. <filename>.txt) . Sorry if I got that wrong...

Comment: no,  I can understand why you'd think that. anyway I sent a e-mail to my teacher to clarify the issue. maybe I got the question requirements wrong. btw, is there such a thing as a not-valid string in the command line? what if I write something like this "a.txt (without the " in the end).

Comment: I don't know in how far this is "standard behaviour" but my terminal prompts me to add the closing quotation marks

Comment: @littlerunaway:  The way the various quotations signs (`"`, `'`, ...) are handled depends on which method is used to invoke the command, whether this is done via a call to a member of the `exec*()` family of functions (see `man 3 exec`) or using a shell. For the latter case it depends on which shell is used (see the  man-pages for the various shells, like `sh`, `csh`, `ksh`, `bash`, `dash`, ...).

Comment: another question if you don't mind. if I'm supposed to write the string to a file in a folder, test/a.txt for example, and suppose the folder already exists, how do I do that?